# Mail marked all my inbox items as read. How do I undo this?

Tags: email

I accidentally deleted all 47,000 e-mails in my inbox. Most were unread. Just after I did this, I issued the command to "undo Delete 47,000 emails". For the last hour the mail activity has been grinding away on my disk and the bar still shows "Copying messages, Moving 23250 messages…" I don't know why it's copying or moving messages since I did "undo" before it had a chance to do anything, but anyway, I noticed that it marked all my gmail items as "read" even though it did not do this to my other inboxes. Also in the console, I'm seeing a lot of messages show up like `3/27/15 5:55:34.620 PM Mail[5285]: open on /Users/me/Library/Mail/V2/Mailboxes/Deleted Messages (Gmail).mbox/EF46037D-AF1B-42A8-B540-A00F046DBD62/Data/0/7/2/1/Messages/1270000.emlx: No such file or directory`.

How do I make it undo setting all my inbox items to read on gmail? Why did it do that? I'm on OS X 10.8.5

Comment: Are they read when you look at them on gmail.com?

Comment: They were all marked for deletion with "message subject" -Trash (and consequently as read). Now the system has to restore them. Depending on your setting the Trash folder will be emptied or stored on the server. If server then recovery can take a while. Once you have them back, select all and mark as Unread.

Comment: So there's no way to restore the read/unread state to what it was before? That really sucks, I don't want to mark messages as unread that I've already read, or vice versa. This is terrible. The software should definitely warn you and ask for your consent before taking potentially irreversible actions!!! I'll be writing a complaint letter to Apple on this one. Now I have 3 years of emails with their read/unread status lost, and no way to get it back. If I had a time machine backup could that possibly help?